# Linkedin Extra Data not populated using python social auth

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api, python-social-auth

I am new with Python social auth.
have followed different questions from StackOverflow but didn't understand. 
I want to get Linkedin profile_url of the user using python social auth.

I have the following setting in my setting.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_FIELD_SELECTORS = ['picture-url', 'email-address', 'headline', 'industry']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_EXTRA_DATA = [('id', 'li_id'),
                               ('firstName', 'first_name'),
                               ('lastName', 'last_name'),
                               ('emailAddress', 'email_address'),
                               ('headline', 'headline'),
                               ('picture-url', 'picture_url')]

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = 'some_key'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'some_secret'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_URL = '/'
```

when I use the following code in my view to get extra data it gives an error:-

```
Exception Type:    KeyError
Exception Value:    'emailAddress'
```

because it emailAddress is not populated in the extra_data field.
only uid,first_name,last_name & access_token is populated in User social auths model.

how to save all user information in the model.?
is there something missing or please give suggestion how to get user information from LinkedIn using python social auth.

Answer (score 0):

forget to use `SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_*` in my `setting.py` 
everything gets populated but `profile_url` is still `null`.

Comment: @CpVerma: Cloud yu please post a pastbin link of your code ?

Comment: can you specify what you did? I have the same problem